# Delete all Events from a calendar with CALDAV

Tags: python, caldav

How can I delete ALL events from a calendar with CALDAV?

I tried this:

```
import caldav

caldav_url = "aaa"
username = "xxx"
password = "xxx"

client = caldav.DAVClient(url=caldav_url ,username=username, password=password)
my_principal = client.principal()
calendars = my_principal.calendars()
my_calendar = my_principal.calendar(name="xxxx")

all_events = my_calendar.events()
for x in all_events:
   print(x.data)
   x.delete
  
# event = my_calendar.events()[0]
# event.delete()
```

But it doesnt work ;(

The last two (commented) lines work for an single event. But I want a loop through ALL events

Comment: `x.delete` shouldn't this be `x.delete()`?

Comment: And what do you mean by it doesn't work? Please elaborate. Does it throw any errors?

Comment: omg. Indeed x.delete(). Shame on me ;(